# Get variations IDs from a variable product in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, children

It is necessary to get the value from the array with the key [0], but the array is in the object. How can I put it in a variable?

```
  WC_Product_Variable Object ( [children:protected] => Array ( [0] => 344 [1] => 345 ) [visible_children:protected] => Array ( [0] => 344 [1] => 345 )
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get the children variation Ids for a variable product, use [`WC_product` `get_children()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#1683-1690) *(that doesn't have/allow any arguments)*:

```
// (if needed) Get an instance of the WC_product object (from a dynamic product ID)
$product = wc_get_product($product_id);

// Get children product variation IDs in an array
$children_ids = $product->get_children();

// Get the first ID value
$children_id = reset($children_ids); 
// or 
$children_id = $children_ids[0];
```

Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you. Worked.

Comment: I have a question. Prompt how to receive for example not the first element, and for example 2 or 3. There already without use of function reset ()

Comment: @AleksPvn `$children_ids` is **an array** of the children variations IDs… so you can use for example: `$second_children_id = $children_ids[1];` or `$third_children_id = $children_ids[2];` … You can even use a `foreach` loop to get something from each variation ID.

Comment: How might you also get the labels from this?

Answer (score 1):

You do not have access to this object because it is protected.

In your case, try to call the method `get_children()`.

```
WC_Product_Variable::get_children(0);
```

Comment: Non-static method WC_Product_Variable::get_children() should not be called statically